# Is it possible to avoid long relative import paths on Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Could you point me to an example of how to configure `Typescript` so that I could just use the name of a file for imports instead of long relative paths?. This implies that the names of the files are **unique** in my entire working directory.

example:

Directories

```
pages/components/foo.js
common/types/abc.js
```

Current import statements

```
import foo from "../../pages/components/foo"
import abc from "../common/types/abc"
```

Desired import statements

```
import foo from "foo"
import abc from "abc"
```

In [Flow](https://flow.org/en/) this is possible using `module.name_mapper` option in its [config](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-regex-string).

Comment: You'd need an additional build tool to make this work. Even then, I don't think TypeScript would be able to resolve these without hard-coded aliases in your tsconfig for every file. All that said: **I do not recommend doing what you are trying to do.**

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to avoid long relative paths, you can do something helpful using "paths" in your tsconfig.json:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@types/*": [
            "common/types/*"
        ],
        "@components/*": [
            "pages/components/*"
        ]
    }
```

So then you can import:

```
import foo from "@components/foo"
import abc from "@types/abc"
```

And these remain the same regardless of the path of the file you're importing to.

I suppose you could use this technique for individual files if you wanted, but I don't think it's a good choice.

Comment: I was getting an error about relative imports for a normal `import` statement that imported a node module, and adding `"baseUrl": "."` to "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json fixed it. Thank you!